# How do I put in a number of collections on homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Instead of [products] which displays products I want to display the available categories on the page instead . How do I do that using php , shortcodes or any other way ? Thank you for your help

Comment: So, do you want to show product category in page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For apply this you have good knowledge about coding

```
<?php
    $prod_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1
    ));
    foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
        $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
?>
<a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?>" /></a>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

If you don't want to do code, you can use the WordPress plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-category-showcase/

Try any solution.